# How to remove duplicate from SQL Aggregate MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve the distinct tuple of a birthdate from my SQL Server table.

```
Select id,insCode,max(birthdate) 
 from birthDateTable 
   where id IN (785412,852963)
      group by id,insCode
```

This query returns duplicate IDs with different values. I want to retrieve the max birthdate from each ID, once.

Comment: You mean different insCode value? Well, someone has to decide which insCode  value to choose, perhaps the one with birthdate =max(birthdate)?

Comment: Each person should have one birthdate. I have to update some birthdate that change due to unknown birthdate. By default one is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all rows for an id which have date = max date for that id:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, insCode, birthdate
  from birthDateTable 
  where id IN (785412,852963)
)
select id, insCode, birthdate
from cte c1
where birthdate = (select max(birthdate) from cte c2
                   where c1.id = c2.id)
```

And how to find id's with multiple, different birthdays:

```
select id
from birthDateTable
group by id
having count(distinct birthdate) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE + row_number:

```
With CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, insCode, birthdate
           rn = row_number() over (Partition by id, insCode Order by birthdate DESC)
    FROM dbo.birthDateTable
)
SELECT id, insCode, birthdate FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```